# Rails app runs locally but crashes on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My RoR app tests out well locally. All tests created pass and the app functions as desired locally when tested with `rails server` as well as with `passenger start`.

Unfortunately, when the app is deployed to AWS EB and delegated one or more AWS EC2 instances, the instance(s) health immediately deteriorates to "degraded" and the auto-scaling/load balancer functionality (if activated) attempts to spin up more instances with the same result.

Visiting the Beanstalk Environment's URL just leads to a blank page (empty source code). I am not sure what to do..  I have identified a few lines from the below error log dump that I believe could be insightful but I have been unable to derive a solution from them:

```
2016/07/13 01:17:42 [error] 2880#0: *4 "/var/app/current/public/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"
2016/07/13 01:17:42 [error] 2880#0: *4 testing "/var/app/current/public" existence failed (2: No such file or directory) while logging request, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"

...

/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/nginx_config_healthd.erb:49:in `get_binding': undefined local variable or method `location_config_filename' for #<PhusionPassenger::Standalone::StartCommand:0x0055afae2de2c8> (NameError)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the full error log from Beanstalk:

---

```
    /var/app/support/logs/production.log
    -------------------------------------
    D, [2016-07-13T01:19:43.479025 #16079] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (4.4ms)[0m  [1m[35mCREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)[0m
    D, [2016-07-13T01:19:43.485867 #16079] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (5.5ms)[0m  [1m[35mCREATE TABLE "ar_internal_metadata" ("key" varchar NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "value" varchar, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)[0m
    D, [2016-07-13T01:19:43.491581 #16079] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
    I, [2016-07-13T01:19:43.493839 #16079]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateLaunchSubscribers (20160711012123)
    D, [2016-07-13T01:19:43.495026 #16079] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
    D, [2016-07-13T01:19:43.495994 #16079] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[35mCREATE TABLE "launch_subscribers" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar, "email" varchar, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)[0m
    D, [2016-07-13T01:19:43.499129 #16079] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35mSQL (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES (?)[0m  [["version", "20160711012123"]]
    D, [2016-07-13T01:19:43.509943 #16079] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (10.7ms)[0m  [1m[36mcommit transaction[0m
    D, [2016-07-13T01:19:43.511887 #16079] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["key", :environment], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    D, [2016-07-13T01:19:43.518319 #16079] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
    D, [2016-07-13T01:19:43.519147 #16079] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35mSQL (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO "ar_internal_metadata" ("key", "value", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["key", "environment"], ["value", "production"], ["created_at", 2016-07-13 01:19:43 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-07-13 01:19:43 UTC]]
    D, [2016-07-13T01:19:43.567003 #16079] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (47.7ms)[0m  [1m[36mcommit transaction[0m



    -------------------------------------
    /var/app/support/logs/passenger.log
    -------------------------------------
    [ 2016-07-13 01:17:39.2862 2860/7f0f1ef76780 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:538 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'webapp', 'cleanup_pidfiles' => 'L3RtcC9wYXNzZW5nZXItc3RhbmRhbG9uZS5veGQ4amEvdGVtcF9kaXJfdG91Y2hlci5waWQ=', 'default_group' => 'webapp', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'webapp', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/tmp/passenger-standalone.oxd8ja/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.60', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'prestart_urls' => 'aHR0cDovLzAuMC4wLjA6ODAA', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'false', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.60', 'web_server_pid' => '2859', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '495', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '497' }
    [ 2016-07-13 01:17:40.3992 2863/7f3cb4136780 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:650 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.2859/generation-0/request
    [ 2016-07-13 01:17:40.8989 2871/7f99ca27c840 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:321 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.2859/generation-0/logging
    [ 2016-07-13 01:17:40.8991 2860/7f0f1ef76780 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
    2016/07/13 01:17:42 [error] 2880#0: *4 "/var/app/current/public/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"
    2016/07/13 01:17:42 [error] 2880#0: *4 testing "/var/app/current/public" existence failed (2: No such file or directory) while logging request, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"



    -------------------------------------
    /var/log/eb-activity.log
    -------------------------------------
      memory. However your system only has 995 MB of total virtual memory (995 MB
      RAM, 0 MB swap). It is recommended that you temporarily add more swap space
      before proceeding. You can do it as follows:

        sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=1M count=1024
        sudo mkswap /swap
        sudo swapon /swap

      See also https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap for more information about
      the swap file on Linux.

      If you cannot activate a swap file (e.g. because you're on OpenVZ, or if you
      don't have root privileges) then you should install Phusion Passenger through
      DEB/RPM packages. For more information, please refer to our installation
      documentation:

        https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/standalone/

      Press Ctrl-C to abort this installer (recommended).
      Press Enter if you want to continue with installation anyway.
      Checking for required software...

       [1m* Checking for C compiler...[0m[37m[40m
            Found: [1m[32myes[0m[37m[40m
            Location: /usr/bin/cc
       [1m* Checking for C++ compiler...[0m[37m[40m
            Found: [1m[32myes[0m[37m[40m
            Location: /usr/bin/c++
       [1m* Checking for GNU make...[0m[37m[40m
            Found: [1m[32myes[0m[37m[40m
            Location: /usr/bin/gmake
       [1m* Checking for Rake (associated with /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby)...[0m[37m[40m
            Found: [1m[32myes[0m[37m[40m
            Location: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rake
       [1m* Checking for OpenSSL development headers...[0m[37m[40m
            Found: [1m[32myes[0m[37m[40m
            Location: /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h
       [1m* Checking for Zlib development headers...[0m[37m[40m
            Found: [1m[32myes[0m[37m[40m
            Location: /usr/include/zlib.h
       [1m* Checking for PCRE development headers...[0m[37m[40m
            Found: [1m[32myes[0m[37m[40m
            Location: /usr/include/pcre.h

      Installing...
      Downloading Nginx 1.8.1 source code...
      Extracting tarball...
      Compiling support libraries (step 1 of 2)...
      ......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
      Compiling Nginx engine (step 2 of 2)...
      ...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
      Compilation finished!

      --------------------------

       [passenger_native_support.so] trying to compile for the current user (root) and Ruby interpreter...
           (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
           Compilation successful. The logs are here:
           /tmp/passenger_native_support-1qzggon.log
       [passenger_native_support.so] successfully loaded.
      /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/nginx_config_healthd.erb:49:in `get_binding': undefined local variable or method `location_config_filename' for #<PhusionPassenger::Standalone::StartCommand:0x0055afae2de2c8> (NameError)
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `eval'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `result'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.29/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command/nginx_engine.rb:177:in `block in write_nginx_config_file'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.29/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command/nginx_engine.rb:170:in `open'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.29/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command/nginx_engine.rb:170:in `write_nginx_config_file'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.29/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command/nginx_engine.rb:41:in `start_engine_real'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.29/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:322:in `start_engine'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.29/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:63:in `run'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.29/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:51:in `run!'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.29/bin/passenger:45:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/passenger:23:in `load'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/passenger:23:in `<main>'
    [2016-07-13T01:21:12.939Z] INFO  [2975]  - [Application deployment app-7e88-160712_211417@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Completed activity. Result:
      Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact.
    [2016-07-13T01:21:12.939Z] INFO  [2975]  - [Application deployment app-7e88-160712_211417@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Starting activity...
    [2016-07-13T01:21:12.939Z] INFO  [2975]  - [Application deployment app-7e88-160712_211417@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployPostHook/01_create_pids.sh] : Starting activity...
    [2016-07-13T01:21:43.111Z] INFO  [2975]  - [Application deployment app-7e88-160712_211417@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployPostHook/01_create_pids.sh] : Completed activity.
    [2016-07-13T01:21:43.111Z] INFO  [2975]  - [Application deployment app-7e88-160712_211417@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Completed activity. Result:
      Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post.
    [2016-07-13T01:21:43.112Z] INFO  [2975]  - [Application deployment app-7e88-160712_211417@1/StartupStage1/PostInitHook] : Starting activity...
    [2016-07-13T01:21:43.112Z] INFO  [2975]  - [Application deployment app-7e88-160712_211417@1/StartupStage1/PostInitHook] : Completed activity. Result:
      Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/postinit.
    [2016-07-13T01:21:43.112Z] INFO  [2975]  - [Application deployment app-7e88-160712_211417@1/StartupStage1] : Completed activity. Result:
      Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup stage 1 completed
    [2016-07-13T01:21:43.112Z] INFO  [2975]  - [Application deployment app-7e88-160712_211417@1/AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
    [2016-07-13T01:21:43.112Z] INFO  [2975]  - [Application deployment app-7e88-160712_211417@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Starting activity...
    [2016-07-13T01:21:43.112Z] INFO  [2975]  - [Application deployment app-7e88-160712_211417@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation/10-config.sh] : Starting activity...
    [2016-07-13T01:21:43.233Z] INFO  [2975]  - [Application deployment app-7e88-160712_211417@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation/10-config.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
      Disabled forced hourly log rotation.
    [2016-07-13T01:21:43.233Z] INFO  [2975]  - [Application deployment app-7e88-160712_211417@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Completed activity. Result:
      Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/logpublish/hooks/config.
    [2016-07-13T01:21:43.233Z] INFO  [2975]  - [Application deployment app-7e88-160712_211417@1/AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
    [2016-07-13T01:21:43.233Z] INFO  [2975]  - [Application deployment app-7e88-160712_211417@1] : Completed activity. Result:
      Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup succeeded
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.190Z] INFO  [19057] - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.190Z] INFO  [19057] - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.190Z] INFO  [19057] - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.190Z] INFO  [19057] - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.190Z] INFO  [19057] - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...



    -------------------------------------
    /var/app/support/logs/access.log
    -------------------------------------
    127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jul/2016:01:17:42 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "-"



    -------------------------------------
    /var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
    -------------------------------------
    [2016-07-13T01:17:01.594Z] DEBUG [2632]  : Refreshing metadata...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:01.597Z] DEBUG [2632]  : Using cached environment metadata.
    [2016-07-13T01:17:01.597Z] DEBUG [2632]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
    [2016-07-13T01:17:01.598Z] DEBUG [2632]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
    [2016-07-13T01:17:01.598Z] INFO  [2632]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish"].
    [2016-07-13T01:17:01.598Z] INFO  [2632]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
    [2016-07-13T01:17:01.599Z] DEBUG [2632]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::CloudFormation::Init||Infra-WriteApplication2||files..
    [2016-07-13T01:17:01.601Z] DEBUG [2632]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||ManifestFileS3Key..
    [2016-07-13T01:17:02.199Z] INFO  [2632]  : Finding latest manifest from bucket 'elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-615201702363' with prefix 'resources/environments/e-n35dn7ryje/_runtime/versions/manifest_'.
    [2016-07-13T01:17:02.732Z] INFO  [2632]  : Found manifest with key 'resources/environments/e-n35dn7ryje/_runtime/versions/manifest_1468372471196'.
    [2016-07-13T01:17:02.794Z] INFO  [2632]  : Updated manifest cache: deployment ID 1 and serial 1.
    [2016-07-13T01:17:02.794Z] DEBUG [2632]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-PreInit.
    [2016-07-13T01:17:02.795Z] INFO  [2632]  : Executing Initialization
    [2016-07-13T01:17:02.795Z] INFO  [2632]  : Executing command: CMD-PreInit...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:02.795Z] INFO  [2632]  : Executing command CMD-PreInit activities...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:02.795Z] DEBUG [2632]  : Setting environment variables..
    [2016-07-13T01:17:02.795Z] INFO  [2632]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-PreInit...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:02.795Z] DEBUG [2632]  : Running stages of Command CMD-PreInit from stage 0 to stage 0...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:02.795Z] INFO  [2632]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-PreInit...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:02.795Z] DEBUG [2632]  : Loaded 3 actions for stage 0.
    [2016-07-13T01:17:02.795Z] INFO  [2632]  : Running 1 of 3 actions: InfraWriteConfig...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:02.797Z] INFO  [2632]  : Running 2 of 3 actions: DownloadSourceBundle...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:03.175Z] INFO  [2632]  : Running 3 of 3 actions: PreInitHook...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:41.091Z] INFO  [2632]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-PreInit...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:41.091Z] INFO  [2632]  : Command CMD-PreInit succeeded!
    [2016-07-13T01:17:41.091Z] INFO  [2632]  : Command processor returning results: 
    {"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[]}]}
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.387Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.387Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.390Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-07977d6c52f370f9d)..
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.390Z] INFO  [2975]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-07977d6c52f370f9d)..
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.390Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.390Z] INFO  [2975]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.390Z] INFO  [2975]  : Received command CMD-Startup: {"execution_data":"{\"leader_election\":\"true\"}","instance_ids":["i-07977d6c52f370f9d"],"command_name":"CMD-Startup","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"2237ea1b-4897-11e6-8db9-ad2a7159939a","command_timeout":"600"}
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.390Z] INFO  [2975]  : Command processor should execute command.
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.390Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Storing current stage..
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.390Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.390Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.390Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.390Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.391Z] INFO  [2975]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish"].
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.392Z] INFO  [2975]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.392Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Refreshing metadata...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.640Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Refreshed environment metadata.
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.640Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.641Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.641Z] INFO  [2975]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish"].
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.642Z] INFO  [2975]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.642Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-Startup.
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.642Z] INFO  [2975]  : Executing Application deployment
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.643Z] INFO  [2975]  : Executing command: CMD-Startup...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.643Z] INFO  [2975]  : Executing command CMD-Startup activities...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.643Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Setting environment variables..
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.643Z] INFO  [2975]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-Startup...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.643Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Running stages of Command CMD-Startup from stage 0 to stage 1...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.643Z] INFO  [2975]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-Startup...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.643Z] INFO  [2975]  : Running leader election...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.887Z] INFO  [2975]  : Instance is Leader.
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.887Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Loaded 7 actions for stage 0.
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.887Z] INFO  [2975]  : Running 1 of 7 actions: HealthdLogRotation...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.892Z] INFO  [2975]  : Running 2 of 7 actions: HealthdHTTPDLogging...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.892Z] INFO  [2975]  : Running 3 of 7 actions: HealthdNginxLogging...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:57.892Z] INFO  [2975]  : Running 4 of 7 actions: EbExtensionPreBuild...
    [2016-07-13T01:17:58.164Z] INFO  [2975]  : Running 5 of 7 actions: AppDeployPreHook...
    [2016-07-13T01:19:43.583Z] INFO  [2975]  : Running 6 of 7 actions: EbExtensionPostBuild...
    [2016-07-13T01:19:43.856Z] INFO  [2975]  : Running 7 of 7 actions: InfraCleanEbExtension...
    [2016-07-13T01:19:43.860Z] INFO  [2975]  : Running stage 1 of command CMD-Startup...
    [2016-07-13T01:19:43.860Z] DEBUG [2975]  : Loaded 3 actions for stage 1.
    [2016-07-13T01:19:43.860Z] INFO  [2975]  : Running 1 of 3 actions: AppDeployEnactHook...
    [2016-07-13T01:21:12.939Z] INFO  [2975]  : Running 2 of 3 actions: AppDeployPostHook...
    [2016-07-13T01:21:43.111Z] INFO  [2975]  : Running 3 of 3 actions: PostInitHook...
    [2016-07-13T01:21:43.112Z] INFO  [2975]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-Startup...
    [2016-07-13T01:21:43.233Z] INFO  [2975]  : Command CMD-Startup succeeded!
    [2016-07-13T01:21:43.233Z] INFO  [2975]  : Command processor returning results: 
    {"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[]}]}
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.184Z] DEBUG [19057] : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.184Z] DEBUG [19057] : Checking if the command processor should execute...
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.187Z] DEBUG [19057] : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-07977d6c52f370f9d)..
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.187Z] INFO  [19057] : Command is applicable to this instance (i-07977d6c52f370f9d)..
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.187Z] DEBUG [19057] : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.187Z] INFO  [19057] : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.187Z] INFO  [19057] : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"execution_data":"{\"aws_access_key_id\":\"ASIAJVMOQJRPGLVNY52Q\",\"signature\":\"TTpp6MvoQzmJMyFtEvAHzKJt0I0=\",\"security_token\":\"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\",\"policy\":\"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\"}","instance_ids":["i-07977d6c52f370f9d"],"data":"6a7bb5b4-4898-11e6-a3c3-37a522e81ab8","command_name":"CMD-TailLogs","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"6a7bb5b4-4898-11e6-a3c3-37a522e81ab8","command_timeout":"600"}
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.187Z] INFO  [19057] : Command processor should execute command.
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.187Z] DEBUG [19057] : Storing current stage..
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.187Z] DEBUG [19057] : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.187Z] DEBUG [19057] : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.187Z] DEBUG [19057] : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.188Z] DEBUG [19057] : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.188Z] INFO  [19057] : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish"].
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.189Z] INFO  [19057] : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.189Z] DEBUG [19057] : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.189Z] INFO  [19057] : Executing CMD-TailLogs
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.190Z] INFO  [19057] : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.190Z] INFO  [19057] : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.190Z] DEBUG [19057] : Setting environment variables..
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.190Z] INFO  [19057] : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.190Z] DEBUG [19057] : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.190Z] INFO  [19057] : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.190Z] DEBUG [19057] : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
    [2016-07-13T01:23:36.190Z] INFO  [19057] : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
```

Comment: You have to add that swap space check that in the log as your instance has less memory you have to use swap space. your local must have more memory so you will not get that error there.

Comment: Hi @error2007s, thanks for the feedback! I'm assuming this means I must add an EBS volume to the Beanstalk app? Or is that not right? Do you have a link you could share regarding this? I really appreciate it!

Comment: Not EBS volume you have to increase the RAM by Memory means the RAM you instance has 1 GB ram only

Comment: It looks like swap is only a warning, not the real issue. Googling for the real error shows results like this: http://serverfault.com/questions/715116/elastic-beanstalk-with-passenger-standalone-working-configuration

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up resolving my issue. My app runs now! Here is what I did:

- Modified the configuration of my Beanstalk environment to use t2.small instance types (instances with 2GB of RAM)
- Set the included version of Phusion Passenger in the .Gemfile to be of a older version (I set it to be `gem "passenger", '~> 4.0.59'` though I think I could get away with a newer version.. but I haven't tested a newer version on EB yet)

The above items were completed per the suggestions in the comments on my question. I did the following after encountering another error message indicating that `secret_key_base` could not be found in production:

- Used the Figaro gem (no specific version) to set the `ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` variable in application.yml
- Added an .ebignore file to ignore all the same files as my .gitignore, EXECPT for application.yml since EB needs this to read the `ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` variable (and my .gitignore ignores this application.yml file since you don't want secrets like API keys, hash values, etc. stored in public view)

Thanks to all that commented. I hope this information helps someone else in the future!